# Spring Security Filter and Posted Data

Tags: spring, spring-security

I wrote a custom Spring Security filter that needs to user XML data that was posted to it.  How would the filter get the posted data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read through the documentation for [AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/apidocs/org/springframework/security/web/authentication/AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.html) (based on your earlier question, I guess this is the class that your custom filter extends), the abstract method to implement is [attemptAuthentication](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/apidocs/org/springframework/security/web/authentication/AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.html#attemptAuthentication%28javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,%20javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse%29), which receives HttpServletRequest and HttpServletResponse as parameters:

```
Parameters:
    request - from which to extract parameters and perform the authentication
    response - the response, which may be needed if the implementation has to do a redirect as part of a multi-stage authentication process (such as OpenID).
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not a really Spring Security-specific problem, since you are likely just implementing the `javax.servlet.Filter` interface. In this case, you are implementing the method:

```
public void doFilter ( ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, 
   FilterChain chain ) throws IOException, ServletException;
```

You can then cast the `ServletRequest` to a `HttpServletRequest` if you need HTTP-specific data (which is usually required):

```
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
// ...
HttpServletRequest httpRequest = (HttpServletRequest) request;
String xml = httpRequest.getParameter("xml");
```

If you are extending one of the standard Spring Security filters, make sure you look at the source for the filter you're extending! Many of them already override `doFilter` and expect that you will override another method to augment their behavior.